# I get a expected an expression error with this struct

Tags: c, struct, expression

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int len;
    int vec[16];
}tvector;

int main(){
    int elem, res;
    tvector v;
    v.len = 16;
    v.vec[16] = {3, 15, 19, 19, 23, 32, 38, 53, 123, 321, 543, 1000, 1123, 6578, 6660, 7999};
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, I get it in line 12 at the first bracket `{`

I've tried other ways around it but it makes it worse, and also did some research but none helped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use an initializer list in an assignment which isn't allowed.  You also can't assign directly to an array, which is what you *think* you're doing but you're actually assigning to a single array element (and one past the end at that).

What you *can* do is initialize the struct at the time is is declared:

```
tvector v = { 16, {3, 15, 19, 19, 23, 32, 38, 53, 123, 321, 543, 1000, 1123, 6578, 6660, 7999} };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method :

```
tvector v = { .len = 16, .vec = {3, 15, 19, 19, 23, 32, 38, 53, 123, 321, 543, 1000, 1123, 6578, 6660, 7999} };
```

You don't have to worry about the order of initialization (here).